# how can i grab a property from an array of JSON objects to use the values of that property as a labels in my chart?

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js, fetch-api

I am trying to plot a chart using chart.js library.I am currently trying to plot the data of json file.

This is the code by which i am able to grab the values of sector and country properties.

```js
const xs = [];
const ys = [];
const api_url = 'jsondata.json';

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const sector = data.map(prop => prop.sector);
  xs.push(sector);
  console.log(sector);
  const country = data.map(prop => prop.country);
  xs.push(country);
  console.log(country);
}

getData();
```

My JSON file looks like this :

```js
[{
    "end_year": "",
    "intensity": 6,
    "sector": "Energy",
    "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
    "country": "United States of America",
  },
  {
    "end_year": "",
    "intensity": 6,
    "sector": "Energy",
    "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
    "country": "United States of America",
  }
]
```

I am trying to grab the values of these properties and use them as labels for x-axis and y-axis respectively.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the values of `prop` and `prop.sector` during mapping?

Comment: How have you tried to get the values? Secondly, what of the data is supposed to be mapped to `x` and `y` respectively?

Comment: I want to map sectors to x-axis and countries to y-axis

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, that is your answer

```js
let json = [{
    "end_year": "",
    "intensity": 6,
    "sector": "Energy",
    "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
    "country": "United States of America",
  },
  {
    "end_year": "",
    "intensity": 6,
    "sector": "Two",
    "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
    "country": "Canada",
  }
];

let sectors = json.map((obj) => {
  return obj.sector
})
let countries = json.map((obj) => {
  return obj.country
})
console.log('sectors:', sectors)
console.log('countries:', countries)
```